# Create Contact List From Existing Emails

Tags: gmail, gmail-contacts

I have over 40,000 emails and I would like to capture all of the email address form my contact list. I would also like to capture all of the CC address in each email to ad to my contact list.

I understand that there would be many duplicates but I think I know how to deal with them.  I'm looking for an easy way to capture all of the email address.

Comment: you want to do this while remaining on Gmail? what kind of tool do you intend to use?

Comment: jmax what I am trying to do is create an email list from all of my emails that I have accumulated over the past 5 years. I want to keep y account with gmail but do not need to use it while the search is going on. I do not know what tool to use.  Thnaks

Answer (score 0):

I can't see any easy way to do it within Gmail.

A solution would be to **download the mails to a desktop client** (with POP or IMAP) for instance Outlook because it is easy to script with VBA. And then parse every mail with VBA and add contacts.

Something like this script: http://www.vbaexpress.com/kb/getarticle.php?kb_id=518